# Incremental variance explained in multivariate multiple linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, variance, multivariate-testing

I try to calculate incremental variance explained by variables in multivariate multiple linear regression model, but I don't have Sum of squares parameters like multiple linear regression. I'd like something like:

```
library(car) 

#Create variables and adjusted the model
set.seed(123)
N  <- 100
X1 <- rnorm(N, 175, 7)
X2 <- rnorm(N, 30, 8)
X3 <- abs(rnorm(N, 60, 30))
Y1 <- 0.2*X1 - 0.3*X2 - 0.4*X3 + 10 + rnorm(N, 0, 10)
Y2 <- -0.3*X2 + 0.2*X3 + rnorm(N, 10)
Y  <- cbind(Y1, Y2)
dfRegr <- data.frame(X1, X2, X3, Y1, Y2)
(fit <- lm(cbind(Y1, Y2) ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data=dfRegr))

#How do we get the proportion now? 

af <- Anova(fit)
afss <- af$"test stat"
print(cbind(af,PctExp=afss/sum(afss)*100))
#
```

Obviously doesn't work. There are some kind of approach for this?

Comment: For this question you might to better on stats.stackexchange

Comment: Thanks Gregor for the comment